# Dimensional Analysis of Force, Work, Energy, and Power

Tags: forces, energy, work, dimensional-analysis, power

I am working on a review of engineering heat transfer, and would like to include a dimensional analysis section in my notes for the relationship between force, work, energy, and power. This is what I have so far:

#### Force

\begin{equation}
[force]=[mass][length][time]^{-2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F=ma=m\frac{ds}{dt^{2}}
\end{equation}

#### Work

\begin{equation}
[work]=[force][length]=[mass][length]^{2}[time]^{-2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
W=Fs=(m\frac{ds}{dt^{2}})(s)
\end{equation}

#### Power

\begin{equation}
[power]=[force][length][time]^{-1}=[mass][length]^{2}[time]^{-3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P=\frac{W}{\Delta t}=\frac{Fs}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}

Would it be better to express work like this:

\begin{equation}
W=Fds=(m\frac{ds}{dt^{2}})(ds)
\end{equation}
?

Could this relation then be expressed like:

\begin{equation}
W=Fs=m\frac{ds^{2}}{dt^{2}}
\end{equation}
?

Can the power equation be expressed like:

\begin{equation}
P=\frac{W}{dt}=m\frac{ds^{2}}{dt^{3}}
\end{equation}?

Is there a flaw in expressing the relationships like this?

I understand that work and energy share the same units, but how would one describe how energy fits into these relationships?

Answer (score 1):

> #### Force
>
> \begin{equation}
> [force]=[mass][length][time]^{-2}
> \end{equation}

> \begin{equation}
> F=ma=m\frac{ds}{dt^{2}}
> \end{equation}

This is wrong. The symbols do not make sense.

Your
$$
\frac{ds}{dt^2}
$$
should be
$$
\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\;,
$$
which means the second derivative of $s$ with respect to $t$. Your $s$ should stand for distance and your $t$ should stand for time.

> Would it be better to express work like this:

> \begin{equation}
> W=Fds=(m\frac{ds}{dt^{2}})(ds)
> \end{equation}
> ?

No. It too doesn't make sense symbolically, just like your force expression.

> Could this relation then be expressed like:

> \begin{equation}
> W=Fs=m\frac{ds^{2}}{dt^{2}}
> \end{equation}
> ?

No. Same reason.

> Can the power equation be expressed like:

> \begin{equation}
> P=\frac{W}{dt}=m\frac{ds^{2}}{dt^{3}}
> \end{equation}?

No. Same reason. And also what you are doing here with the differentials doesn't make sense. The differentials look like fractions, and sometimes can be treated like fractions, but not all the time. You need to understand calculus to know when and why.

> Is there a flaw in expressing the relationships like this?

Yes, your equations don't even make sense symbolically/syntactically, let alone semantically.